# Loading data from firebase into android recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have being trying to fetch data from my firebase database into a recyclerview in android studio but each time I try, the app keeps crashing. I have tried debugging and all that but none seem to help.
Below are my codes:

**The Error**

```
--------- beginning of crash
    2019-12-18 08:43:24.107 5409-5409/com.example.shoptest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shoptest, PID: 5409
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to 
    android.widget.TextView
    at com.example.shoptest.PopularAdapter$ImageViewHolder.<init>(PopularAdapter.java:68)
    at com.example.shoptest.PopularAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PopularAdapter.java:33)
    at com.example.shoptest.PopularAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PopularAdapter.java:17)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline
    (RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at 
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    .onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    2019-12-18 08:43:24.107 5409-5409/com.example.shoptest E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.shoptest;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public PopularAdapter adapter;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private List<Popular> mPopular;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));


    showPopularProducts();
}

public void showPopularProducts() {

    mPopular = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("popular");

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Popular popular = postSnapShot.getValue(Popular.class);
                mPopular.add(popular);
            }

            adapter = new PopularAdapter(MainActivity.this, mPopular);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

**Popular Activity**

```
public class Popular {

private String product_image;
private String product_name;
private String product_price;

public Popular(){}

public Popular(String product_image, String product_name, String product_price) {
    this.product_image = product_image;
    this.product_name = product_name;
    this.product_price = product_price;
}

public String getProduct_image() {
    return product_image;
}

public void setProduct_image(String product_image) {
    this.product_image = product_image;
}

public String getProduct_name() {
    return product_name;
}

public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

public String getProduct_price() {
    return product_price;
}

public void setProduct_price(String product_price) {
    this.product_price = product_price;
}
```

}

**Popular Adapter**

```
public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Popular> mPopular;

public PopularAdapter(Context mContext, List<Popular> mPopular) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPopular = mPopular;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.popular_item, parent, false);

    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Popular popularCur = mPopular.get(position);

    holder.prod_name.setText(popularCur.getProduct_name());
    holder.prod_price.setText(popularCur.getProduct_price());

    Picasso.get()
            .load(popularCur.getProduct_image())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into((Target) holder.prod_img);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPopular.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView prod_name, prod_price, prod_img;


    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        prod_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodName);
        prod_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodPrice);
        prod_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodImag);

    }
}
```

}

**Main Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:text="Popular Products"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Popular item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/prodImag"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/prodName"
            android:text="Product"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="$$200"
                android:id="@+id/prodPrice"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Database on Firebase**

[database from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjHrq.png)

I'm really forward to getting a solution to this problem, for this project is one I need to complete before the year ends :( Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Class Cast Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) - you are casting `ImageView` to `TextView` in `ImageViewHolder`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to 
android.widget.TextView
```

Comment: "I did the changes but nothing worked :( " what changes did you do, what does it say now?

Comment: Good news :) I did what you guys recommended, that is, changing the textView to an imageView and it did the trick. I'm so happy guys. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`prod_img` is of type `TextView` and the id `prodImag` is an id for an `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView

            android:id="@+id/prodImag"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

Therefore change the type of `prod_img` to `ImageView`

Comment: I have changed that but it doesn't seem to solve the problem :(

Comment: I get this error now after making the corrections:                                                           2019-12-19 14:39:51.499 6421-6428/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2019-12-19 14:39:51.850 6421-6421/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: It works now sir. I did exactly what you recommended :)